# Pyspark - Orderly min value until a given date in a dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Imagine I have a dataframe as follows:

| date | timestamp | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-05 | 2022-01-05 06:00:00 | -0.3 |
| 2022-01-04 | 2022-01-04 04:00:00 | -0.6 |
| 2022-01-03 | 2022-01-03 15:00:00 | -0.1 |
| 2022-01-03 | 2022-01-03 10:00:00 | -0.15 |
| 2022-01-02 | 2022-01-02 14:00:00 | -0.3 |
| 2022-01-02 | 2022-01-02 12:00:00 | -0.1 |
| 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-01 12:00:00 | -0.2 |

I want to create a column with the latest min value until the date of the `timestamp`
So the outcome would be:

| date | timestamp | value | min_value_until_now |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-05 | 2022-01-05 06:00:00 | -0.3 | -0.6 |
| 2022-01-04 | 2022-01-04 04:00:00 | -0.6 | -0.3 |
| 2022-01-03 | 2022-01-03 15:00:00 | -0.1 | -0.3 |
| 2022-01-03 | 2022-01-03 10:00:00 | -0.15 | -0.3 |
| 2022-01-02 | 2022-01-02 14:00:00 | -0.3 | -0.2 |
| 2022-01-02 | 2022-01-02 12:00:00 | -0.1 | -0.2 |
| 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-01 12:00:00 | -0.2 | -0.2 |

On `2022-01-01` there is not historical data and thus I can just substitute it by `-0.2` which is the only point available at the beginning.

How can I do this? I tried with windowing but with no success.
Important to note is that the `min_value_until_now` should decrease monotonically.

Any help would be duly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `min` function over a Window:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

w = Window.orderBy("timestamp").rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, -1)

df.withColumn(
    "min_value_until_now",
    F.coalesce(F.min("value").over(w), F.col("value"))
).show()

#+----------+-------------------+-----+-------------------+
#|      date|          timestamp|value|min_value_until_now|
#+----------+-------------------+-----+-------------------+
#|2022-01-01|2022-01-01 12:00:00| -0.2|               -0.2|
#|2022-01-02|2022-01-02 12:00:00| -0.1|               -0.2|
#|2022-01-02|2022-01-02 14:00:00| -0.3|               -0.2|
#|2022-01-03|2022-01-03 10:00:00|-0.15|               -0.3|
#|2022-01-03|2022-01-03 15:00:00| -0.1|               -0.3|
#|2022-01-04|2022-01-04 04:00:00| -0.6|               -0.3|
#|2022-01-05|2022-01-05 06:00:00| -0.3|               -0.6|
#+----------+-------------------+-----+-------------------+
```

Note that using a non-partitioned Window could have bad performance effects. You should add a `partitionBy` clause if you have a column `ID` on which you can partition.

Comment: That'S not doing what I want:

--> 2022-01-02  2022-01-02 14:00:00  -0.3  -0.2

and yours is -0.3. I want the lowest value on record before the event happened.

Comment: @MiloVentimiglia ah you don't want the current row value to be included. updated above solution to use `rowsBetween`.

Comment: Just for my understanding, what is the function of the coalesce? is just to avoid nulls when there's no historical data?

Comment: @MiloVentimiglia yes

Comment: Hi @blackbishop. This answer is great both in simplicity and performance. Finally, I comprehend well how rowBetween works. It basically narrows the rows within the window. Thanks for the help.